# Use Java keyword volatile within an EMF model

Tags: java, concurrency, eclipse-rcp, volatile, emf

We use EMF 2.7 together with a multithreaded Eclipse RCP 3.x application. Now some EMF models and features/properties, respectively, are accessed by different threads. So we need to make those variables `volatile` [1].

Is there a way in the .ecore or .ecorediag files to configure the properties of an EMF model in such a way that the code generator will automatically add the `volatile` keyword in the generated model code? or do we have to manually add it in the generated code (as unsuitable as it is..)?

It would be very useful if 'volatile' could be specified in the model definition instead of in the generated code.

Here's an example of a manually added volatile in a generated EMF model:

```
public class EGuiStateImpl extends MinimalEObjectImpl.Container implements 
     EGuiState {
/**
* @generated NOT
*/
protected volatile ESummary summary;
```

[1] the Java keyword `volatile` is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified by different threads.

Answer (score 1):

EMF generated models by default are not prepared for multi-threading. "Volatile" in EMF means the property (a.k.a, feature) won't generate any field, it has nothing to do with the volatile syntax from Java. 
(You should read the EMF book or at least the EMF Refcardz)

You could always modify the javajet templates to generate different code, but again, this is not recommended since default EMF generation was not designed for multi-threading.

In case you need a multi-threading EMF-based application, consider to use EMF [CDO](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDO) which also supports transactions.

Answer (score 0):

In the ecore model under the EClass select the EAttribute or EReference that you want to make volatile. Right click->Show Properties. At the end of the properties view there is a `Volatile` setting that defaults to `false'.

Note: I haven't actually tried it, but I'm guessing changing that should work.

Comment: No this does not work. Unfortunately EMF has its own notion of volatile, "a volatile attribute is one for which no storage is set aside at runtime" [EMFbook]. So when I do this, the generator actually removes the class variable and creates an empty accessor method with a TODO as follows:  
  
`@Override
  public ESummary getSummary() {
    // TODO: implement this method to return the 'Summary' attribute
    // Ensure that you remove @generated or mark it @generated NOT
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }`

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. In which case I can't find any combination of attributes or other settings that would mark it as `volatile`. `@Generated NOT` might be the only option.